# How to crawl internal links via javascript?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to crawl all the internal links of a site but running into some issues getting the links to crawl via scrapy as it looks like they are being generated via javascript. One page for example of this site is here https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/274468-wavy-lines-pastel-background

I have tried running the below code and not having luck getting links/tags in the section called *"This Image Appears In Searches For"* on the page

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from datablogger_scraper.items import DatabloggerScraperItem


class DatabloggerSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = "vecteezycrawl"


allowed_domains = ["www.vecteezy.com"]


start_urls = ["https://www.vecteezy.com"]


rules = [
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            canonicalize=True,
            unique=True
        ),
        follow=True,
        callback="parse_items"
    )
]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, 
dont_filter=True)


def parse_items(self, response):

    items = []
   links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, 
unique=True).extract_links(response)


        is_allowed = False
        for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
            if allowed_domain in link.url:
                is_allowed = True

        if is_allowed:
            item = DatabloggerScraperItem()
            item['url_from'] = response.url
            item['url_to'] = link.url
            items.append(item)

    return items
```

The links I am trying to get would be to the tags you see below this image appears in searches for: pastel background, pastel, background, abstract, wavy, line, diagonal, seamless..etc

Looks like after some updates I could get it to start crawling more but now it won't crawl the entire site? Here's the dump after the crawl completed

*INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:*

```
{'downloader/exception_count': 10746,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 10742,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 7457136941,
 'downloader/request_count': 233585,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 233585,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 929365695,
 'downloader/response_count': 233581,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 23618,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 23,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 183088,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 26806,
 'downloader/response_status_count/504': 40,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1797531,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 21, 11, 10, 143192),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 184160,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/400': 183088,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/500': 1072,
 'item_scraped_count': 2066100,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2311531,
 'log_count/INFO': 184277,
 'offsite/domains': 30,
 'offsite/filtered': 505814,
 'request_depth_max': 211,
 'response_received_count': 207778,
 'retry/count': 25778,
 'retry/max_reached': 1072,
 'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 25734,
 'retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out': 40,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 244326,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 244326,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 244326,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 244326,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 19, 21, 28, 203714)}
```

Comment: (1) Those links are not rendered via Javascript. You can confirm by using the Scrapy shell.
(2) There is a missing for-loop `for link in links:`
(3) What are you trying to do? Do you want your crawler to extract and return only the tag names? Or should it further crawl them and extract *all* links on the site?

Comment: I want the crawler to find every ahref on this site and crawl them while logging every from and to link found. I can't get these links to be found when scraping this page.

Comment: @malberts if I add the for link in links it will find those links? Where do I add that?

Comment: I was able to tweak a few more things to get more links but I am not getting the entire site crawled, still running into issues. Here is what it spits out at the end of the crawl it looks like maybe its throwing alot of 5xx errors and the server cant handle the crawl?

Comment: First of all, be aware that you are not allowed to scrape that website as per their [Terms of Use](https://www.vecteezy.com/terms). Secondly, if you are hammering that site with a full crawl without any sort of delays then you might very well get failed pages because you are overloading their server.